# Find the derivative of $g\circ f^{-1}$ where $g(x) = x^{3}-x$ and $f(x)= x^{3} + x$.

Tags: calculus

Find the derivative of $g\circ f^{-1}$ where $g(x) = x^{3}-x$ and $f(x)= x^{3} + x$ at $x=2$.

My attempt:

\begin{align*}\frac{d(g\circ f^{-1})}{dx} &= g'(f^{-1}(x))((f^{-1})'(x))(f'(x))\\&= g'(f^{-1}(2))(f^{-1}(2))'(f'(2))\end{align*}

$$\{ (f^{-1})'(f(x))= 1/f'(x) => (f^{-1}(2))' = 1/f'(1) = 1/4 \}$$

\begin{align*} &= g'(1)(1/4)(13)\\
 &= 2.\frac{1}{4}.13\\
 &= 13/2\end{align*}

Is this right way to find the derivative.

Answer is given = $1/2$

Comment: `\circ` gives the composition symbol.

Comment: Your computation is wrong; you have an extra $f’(x)$ that does not belong there at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $h(x) = f^{-1}(x)$. Then you have
$$\frac{d}{dx}(g\circ h)(x) = g’(h(x)) h’(x).$$
Your error lies in having an extra $f’(x)$ at the end of that formula, for no apparent reason.

Now; what is $h’(x)$? You can use the Inverse Function Theorem: if $f(a)=b$, then
$$(f^{-1})’(b) = \frac{1}{f’(a)}.$$
Here note that $f(1)=2$. So
$$(f^{—1})’(2) = \frac{1}{f’(1)}.$$
You should be able to proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct, except that you applied the chain rule incorrectly in the first step; applying the chain rule should instead give
$$(g\circ f^{-1})'(x)=g'(f^{-1}(x))\cdot (f^{-1})'(x)$$
where there is no factor of $f'(x)$ - this is just taking the rule for any two functions and applying it to one that *happens* to be the inverse of some other function. This is why your answer is off by a factor of $13$: you multiplied by $f'(2)=13$ unnecessarily.

It's worth noting that you can do this a bit more clearly with differentials; if you say that $y=g(f^{-1}(x))$ you can define $z=f^{-1}(x)$ and note that $f(z)=x$ and $y=g(z)$. Then you get
$$dx=f'(z)\,dz$$
$$dy=g'(z)\,dz$$
and hence
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{g'(z)}{f'(z)}$$
and since you can calculate $z=1$ when $x=2$, this gives the answer in a straightforwards manner.